# Script to get duration

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I am new to PostgreSQL. I am trying to write a query which can give me duration of the time. The fields are in the format `yyyymmddhhmmss`. In between we will get empty fields for `Start_Time` or `End_Time`. I want to skip these rows and get the output.

```
Start_Time          End_Time 
20130312080535   20130312080550
20130312080018   20130312080028
20130312080030   20130312080049
20130311154049   20130311154138
20130311225510  
20130311152500   20130311152538
20130311225510  
20130311152539   20130311152614
20130311152740   20130311152806
```

Comment: What is "duration of the time" supposed to mean? If you are not sure of the language you can always supply a sample output to clarify what you are after. Also, you need to supply the data types of the columns and *always* the version of PostgreSQL - even if it shouldn't matter much in this case.

Comment: @shabu - did you get the info you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
  to_timestamp(end_time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') -
  to_timestamp(start_time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') as "time_interval"
FROM
  measurement
WHERE
  end_time IS NOT NULL;
```

There's an sqlfiddle if you want to adjust your question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/576d4/6

Comment: What is measurement in here?

Comment: It's explained in the link. It is just a test table I made to test and explain the query.